# Desktop Docker and Manual Proxy Configuration Bug

Tags: docker, http-proxy

I am running Desktop Docker 2.5.1 on Windows.  I recently had an issue where I could not pull any images from docker hub.  I typically run behind a corporate VPN and usually everything works as expected.

What happened was that I was curious what would happen if I disconnected from the VPN and went through a proxy server instead.  I configured desktop docker -> settings -> resources -> proxies and enabled manual proxy configuration and filled in both HTTP and HTTPS values.  At this point I had to attend to something else and so I disabled manual proxy configuration (but left the values in place) and then clicked Apply & Restart.

The next time I tried to pull a docker from the hub (with or w/o VPN) I had problems:

- with VPN I got the error:

> error response from daemon: get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/:
> net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection

- without VPN I got the error:

> proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup amec.zscaler.mycompany.com on
> 192.168.65.1:53: no such host

After spending hours googling the errors and talking to corporate tech support I decided to re-enable manual proxy configuration and delete the entries for the two proxies and then disable the configuration, apply and restart desktop docker.

This fixed my issue.  I'm posting this so that perhaps it may help others.